# jQuery Datatable - Export and Email

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-data, jquery-datatables-editor

I am able to export jQuery Datatable data to Excel/PDF or CSV format but does it is possible to send this report as attachment or can we parse the data and draft a mail including datatable as Mail body?

I have tried to parse using  table.buttons.exportData(); but while spliting using comma (",") as my record has date with "," format spliting logic does not work.

Comment: have you figured out how to do this. i'm trying to share it on whatsapp. share your code, if you have any.